# NetBeans 8.0.2 fails to start Tomcat because of missing catalina.bat

Tags: java, netbeans, tomcat7, samba, catalina

I just finished setting up the prelimanary steps for a Java Web project on NetBeans. I installed NetBeans and created a network drive using Samba on my home Ubuntu Server, which has Tomcat7. When I try to run the example Hello World project, i get the following error:

Starting of Tomcat failed, the Z:\usr\share\tomcat7\bin\catalina.bat startup script is missing.
C:\Users\\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1150: Starting of Tomcat failed, the Z:\usr\share\tomcat7\bin\catalina.bat startup script is missing.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)

I checked the directory its is referencing and there is a catalina.sh file but no .bat file. Anyone know hints to get this file or how to get NetBeans to run the .sh file instead?

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the appropiate zip file from https://tomcat.apache.org/. I use Tomcat 8.0.33 and I download zip file from the zip link in the Binary Distributions subsection of the 8.0.3 section [download zip file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWGgn.png).
2. Open the zip file (you don't need uncompress it), go to bin folder, copy the catalina.bat file.
3. Go to Apache Tomcat bin folder in you machine and paste the catalina.bat file.
4. Go to you NetBeans, click on Services tag (window -> services), left click in ApacheTomcat, click Start option
5. If must copy other files like setclasspath.bat, go to step 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows, Netbeans need the `.bat` file, not the `.sh` file.

`catalina.bat` file is distributed with the Tomcat binary distribution.

It's not in your path means either you have mingled with the files or you have downloaded wrong distribution (eg: source distribution).

So download a fresh copy of tomcat from [here](http://mirror.sdunix.com/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.64/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.64.zip), set the path correctly and try again.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason that I don't know, if you download the **zip** version of Tomcat, the `.bat`s are there. It's not the same for the **installer** version though. (I am on Windows BTW, I don't know what happens on Linux.)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is  happening when you are using  the installer, use the distribution copy. it worked for me